# ember data lost data after reload

Tags: javascript, session, ember.js, ember-data

I use ember-data, and every time my page is reloaded, I lose my data in the store.
I am implementing an external payment, after the payment page (external). my user returns to the confirmation page but with an empty store.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please, take a look on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember-data store is only in memory and therefore isn't persisted after page ist reloaded. You could try to persist the store in local- or session storage but I dont't think that's the way to go, because the result would be unnecessary complex.

The possible solutions dependent on the data in your store. If the data is also persisted in backend it can be retrieved again. If not, it may be should or you could persist the data in the URL as query params instead.

Otherwise you could also open a new window/tab for the external payment page or display an modal dialog as overlay with an iframe that points to the payment page.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to save your model before reload.
And find saved records after reload.

If your model has id=null before reload, it will be removed from DS after reload.